# How to call action in react before the first load of page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an action in `componentDidMount` that is called by click

```
onBtnClick = (data: any) => {
  this.props.componentDidMount(data);
};

<button onClick={this.onBtnClick}> Toogle posts </button>;
{
  this.props.data.map((el: any) => <li key={el.id}>{el.title}</li>);
}
```

How can I call `componentDidMount` before the first page load? Without using onClick function

Comment: Consider not naming a prop after a react method. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I assume you are passing a components `componentDidMount` method as a prop? If so, it's very bad practice.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I`m trying to call this.props.componentDidMount before the first load of page..

Comment: The method is named `componentDidMount` which means the component _must have been mounted_, which strongly implies that the page is _already loaded_.

Comment: @Chris Yes, you are right.It will work. But I`m trying to learn redux and I wanna componentDidMount be action.

Comment: @Moo name the function something else, and call it from componentDidMount as a starting point. It's a bad idea to call defined react methods directly as they have a specific mental model in terms of when they run.

Comment: If you want to run some code that you have inside cDM, simply move all of that logic to a separate method. You can then call that method from cDM **and** pass the method as a prop

Comment: What do you mean "before first page"? Is it mean "how to call it before first page of the whole app"?

Comment: If you want to call it as the component 'loads' (as you put it) why not put a call to your specific function (not named componentDidMount()) in the constructor?

Comment: @Artem Dudkin before the first LOAD of my page

Comment: If you want to perform some operations before the page loads then all you need is `componentWillMount`, which gets called before the first render of a component. But since this lifecycle method is now deprecated in latest version of react, I would suggest to put your logic in parent component and on successful execution navigate/render this component. Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 2):

`componentDidMount`is a lifecycle method in React, and it is called after the component is successfully rendered. You should not pass this a prop to any other component.

If you want a function or action to be called before the page fully loaded (Before componentDidMount is called), you need to use `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()`, which is deprecated, and I suggest you do not use it. Or you could call the action directly in the `constructor()` method. The constructor is the first thing that is called.

Another important thing to know, is that you should not call lifecycle methods from `onClick()` functions, they are being handled and called appropriately by React itself.

If you need to pass the component as a prop. Create a function called `myCustomComponentDidMount()`, not `componentDidMount()`, and then call it from the `constructor()`, which is before the first load of the application, and then you can also pass the function as a prop to others, without conflicting with `componentDidMount()`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code structure below. For Redux, you need the `connect()` function available in the `react-redux` package. When the `connect()` function is called, your redux state is automatically mapped to the props of the component so you don't need to pass props again and you don't need `componentDidMount()` or `componentWillMount()`. Simply reference this.props.

I have also added some comments for your reference.

```
// Initial internal state of the component.   
  state = {}

  toggleButton() {
    // do something when the button is clicked.   }

  componentWillMount() {
    // DEPRECATED METHOD
    // Anything you want to call before the component mounts.   }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Anything you want to call after the component mounts.   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onBtnClick}>Toggle posts</button>

        <ul>
          { 
            // check that the data is available before rendering.
            this.props.data && this.props.data.map(el => (
            <li key={el.id}>{el.title}</li>
          ))
          }
        </ul>

      </div>
    )   } }

// If using Redux, you will need to use mapStateToProps()

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ data: state.data })

connect(mapStateToProps)(/* Your component */ )
```

Hope this helps [React-Redux Doc](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect)